# Filters for searching a list<object>

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an Object with the following definition:

```
class Obj {
    public string Id;
    public string Vendor;
    public string Type;
}
```

then a list:

```
List<Obj>
```

I have a checkedlistbox component where the user can select the filters to return results.

Example:

User check [cb1 = VENDORX, cb2 = VENDORY, cb3 = TYPEONE]

return a list where `Obj.Vendor = VENDORX or VENDORY and Obj.Type = TYPEONE`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** by including a [mcve]. See also [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using LinQ

```cs
var filtered = objs.Where(o => o.Vendor is "VENDOROX" or "VENDORY" && o.Type == "TYPEONE");

// same as 
var filtered = objs.Where(o => (o.Vendor == "VENDOROX" || o.Vendor == "VENDORY") && o.Type == "TYPEONE");
```

Comment: @Igor I understand your point, I'll update my answer as the question changes.